# Discord.py delete messages and allow specific message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I allow users send only the specific message and delete every other message!

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if not msg.content == 'specific_msg':
        await client.delete_message(msg)
```

You have to give **Manage Messages** permission to your bot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method and add the messages you want to allow in the `msgs` variable.

```py
msgs=['hi there','hello there']

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.content.lower() not in msgs:
        await bot.delete_message(msg)

    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```